# Reactjs - this.state.data.map arguments is UNDEFINED

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

ive been trying to fetch data from my api but its somehow confusing that `this.state.Data.map` does work but the argument `dynamicdata` is undefined.

in `App.js`  react

```
class ShowAll extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        Data: [],
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
          Request.get('/budget').then((res)=>{
            let DataString = JSON.stringify(res.body);
            this.setState({
              Data: DataString
            }, function(){
              console.log(DataString);
            })
          }).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          {
            this.state.Data.map(function(dynamicData, key){
              <div>{dynamicData[0]._id}</div>  // doesn't render anything and throws an error message saying TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

            })
          }
          </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 1 **

The api data structure is

```
 [{
    "_id":"lul",
    "_creator":"5a8f8ecdd67afa6494805bef",
    "firstItem":"hero",
    "secondItem":"30",
    "thirdItem":"3",
    "__v":0,
    "tBudget":9,
    "thirdPrice":3,
    "secondPrice":3,
    "firstPrice":3
    }]
```

Comment: What's returning your server? Maybe `res.body` is not an iterable object? hard to guess without knowing the value of `res.body`

Comment: `res.body` does return the data i want. i checked using `console.log()`. its all fine but i cant access a specific item of the object. check post edit for structure

each object in the api has this structure. and im trying to access _id or whatever in there

Comment: Totally, seems that the problem is with the response from the api. `Array.from` expect an array-like or iterable object. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the data you are getting from an API call

Comment: First issue is with your data shape assumption inside the `map` (there isn't `[0]` property inside your array items), and that's why the cannot read property error raises. Once this is fixed, you need to return the jsx element from the `map`, and include a `key` property on this jsx element. Read about special attribute `key` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh. Your original post was a *completely* different problem.

Two problems. First:

You're mapping, so you don't need to index the mapped value

```
this.state.Data.map(function(dynamicData, n) {
  // dynamicData _is_ the nth element in the array, you don't need dynamicData[x]
  dynamicData._id === "lul"
})
```

second, you're not returning anything from your map callback

```
map(function(...) {
  return (<div>...</div>)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) i kinda feel bad i didn't figure the return thing out myself.

Comment: Also keep in mind you need to add an unique `key` property to each jsx element returned from the mapping function. Read more about key prop [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the server response, you don't need to access the item 0 when rendering each one of them

```
class ShowAll extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        Data: [],
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
          Request.get('/budget').then((res)=>{

            this.setState({
              Data: res.body, // Assuming res.body is already an array
            }, function(){
              console.log(DataString);
            })
          }).catch((err)=> console.log(err));
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          {
            this.state.Data.map((dynamicData, key) => // Using an arrow function
              <div>{dynamicData._id}</div>  // Don't access the item 0
            )
          }
          </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

The previous code assumes `res.body` is already an array. If that's not the case and you are actually getting a string or something else, you need to parse the response and make sure you assign an array to the state.

Comment: Thank you. the `res.body` is an object. thats why i converted it before doing anything. it works now after adding the return before `<div>{dynamicData._id}</div> `

Comment: When using an arrow function (with one statement) you don't need to add the return as by default it returns the result of the expression, in this case the JSX element ;)

Comment: believe it or not , it doesnt work without the return. thats the main issue here as everything was right except the return. i removed it now to try and it didnt work as before. thanks anyways.